# Does graphics tablet language matter?

Tags: drawing-tablet, hardware-recommendation, wacom

I want to buy a Wacom graphics tablet. I live in Switzerland, where we have multiple national languages (French, German, Italian, ...). I was looking at the prices of the tablet on different websites and noted that they specify the language of the tablet. The one I want to buy is a *German-Italian* version but I speak only french. So I was wondering:

Does the graphics tablet's language matter ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bought mine from a german retailer, and did not get anything in german at all. Software is in english, even the box was in english. Not sure what they could be referring to.

Comment: Yeah and I can't find anything on the internet. Seems like that doesn't matter. Thanks for your example.